# Matplotlib live plot of data update

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to liveplot some data acquired by instruments.
The following works (random data as an example):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
from itertools import count
import time

%matplotlib qt  

fields, volts = [], []
index = count()

def animate(i):    
    global fields, volts
    fields.append(next(index))
    volts.append(random.randint(0, 5))
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(fields, volts)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 1000)
plt.show()
```

... but I need to have the data update *outside* of **FuncAnimation**, in it own loop.
I believed it could work, but the following code just opens the window and doesnt update it until I stop the program:

```
fields, volts = [], []
index = count()

def animate(i):    
    global fields, volts
    
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(fields, volts)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 1000)
plt.show()

while (True):
    time.sleep(1)
    fields.append(next(index))
    volts.append(random.randint(0, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, FuncAnimation calls your animate periodically so you could shift your append statements into that loop and also control the interval using the `interval` keyword argument.

```py
fields, volts = [], [] 
index =iter(range(20)) 
from numpy import random 
 
def animate(i):     
    global fields, volts 
    fields.append(len(volts)) 
    volts.append(random.randint(0,5)) 
    plt.cla() 
    plt.plot(fields, volts, c='c') 
 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=20, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```